# Google DFP: setting up large groups of ad units and placements

Tags: google-dfp

I'm trying to determine the best way to determine my Ad Unit and Placement definitions. 
I have a website that has groups, info pages and aggregation pages. All these elements can have a category associated with it, e.g. Nutrition, which can be an overarching channel.

So we may have groups about Nutrition where people discuss it or infopages where a manufacturer gives info about a particular product. All this info for Nutrition is aggregated on the Nutrition page.

Users may also create their own groups.

My requirements are:

- Some groups, infopages and aggregation pages are sponsored by a particular sponsor. In this area only his ads may show up and certainly no ads from competing competing players.
- I want to be able to target categories such as Nutrition
- In some cases I need to target specific groups, aggregation pages or infopages

So, I initially thought to create Ad Unit definition like this

- Groups: groups_%groupId_%adunitSize, for each group add Placement tags such as Groups, Nutrition
- InfoPages: pages_%pageId_%adunitSize, for each page add Placement tags such as Pages, Nutrition
- Aggregation: aggr_%categoryId_%adunitSize, for each aggregation add Placement tags such as Aggregation, Nutrition

The problem here is that users can create their own groups, so I might generate an adunit-id on the website that doesn't exist in Google DFP. Also this creates a huge number of Ad Units, I have a script that can spit them out so I can import those, but it still feels wrong.

Another approach I thought of was to do it like this.

- Groups: groups_%adunitSize, for each group add Placement tags such as Groups, Nutrition, but also a unique id: G%groupId
- InfoPages: pages_%adunitSize, for each page add Placement tags such as Pages, Nutrition, but also a unique id: P%pageId
- Aggregation: aggr_%adunitSize, for each aggregation add Placement tags such as Aggregation, Nutrition, but also a unique id: A%categoryId

I figured that in this case, I would avoid the risk of non-existing units while still having the ability to target highly specific Ad units. Of course, this would explode the number of Placements and I'm not even sure that is allowed.

And there is the approach

- Groups: groups_Nutrition_%adunitSize, for each group add Placement tags such as Groups, Nutrition
- InfoPages: pages_Nutrition_%adunitSize, for each page add Placement tags such as Pages, Nutrition
- Aggregation: aggr_Nutrition_%adunitSize, for each aggregation add Placement tags such as Aggregation

In all cases, I'm not sure how to make sure how for some pages we can create a 100% exposure for the Sponsor. Any suggestions are most appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programing, but rather about configuring something within a 3rd party system.

Comment: I would rather discuss the actual question than debate whether it might be programming or configuration. I could call it a question of architecture.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery on your page I created a [DFP plugin](https://github.com/coop182/jquery.dfp.js) that might at least solve some of the issues that you are having.

The plugin adds the ability to target ad units based on the current URL etc... so that might be of some use to you.

Even if the plugin is not useful as far as DFP architecture for your site, I think you should only create ad units based on their position on the page.. e.g. HeaderAd, RightSideBar, FooterAD

Once you have all of your possible Ad units setup in terms of page position then you can just use page level targeting to fill them with relevant ads... it sounds like you only need to create 4 targeting keywords: Category, Group, Page, Aggregation

You could add all of the ad units to a placement and then target line items at the placement and add your custom criteria for the category etc and everything should be handled easily.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I didn't realize you could use url based targeting, that would solve a lot of issues. Any suggestions where I might read up on that?

Comment: You cant use URL targeting with regular DFP, but the jQuery plugin which I linked allows you to do it, its all explained on the link I posted.